# Dynamically set MenuItem color in Android

Tags: android

When I'm adding items to the options `Menu` in Android, is it possible to also set a custom foreground color for each of the items?

Let's say I need to add five items (programmatically), I need to set each of those items to 5 different colors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to also set a custom foreground color for each of the
>   items?

Yes, is possible. You can use `Drawable` class to achieve.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nemu_main, menu);
    Drawable yourdrawable = menu.getItem(0).getIcon(); // value 0 indicate item position
    yourdrawable.mutate();
    yourdrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    return true;
}
```

In your case, you need to create 5 drawable variables.

Comment: Awesome. Any way to do this in a more straightforward way when I'm doing `menu.add`?